# How the second form of following equation is derived form first form (i.e. given first line, what are the steps involved in writing second line

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation, products

[image]

How the second form of following equation is derived form first form (i.e. what are the steps involved in writing second line)

Comment: I cannot see what those commas could possibly be doing in the denominator